# Two-way interaction by yield as exception

Tags: python, dll, python-3.3

I write C++ DLL which is gate between Meta Trader 4 aplication (MT4) and Python scripts (embedding Python to MT4). MT4 sends request to this DLL and wait for instructions to do (array of string command for example). DLL deliver parsing of MT4 request to Python scripts. Python scripts need achieve some information from MT4 for parse each request. Therefore MT4 and Python have two-way communication.

But MT4 does not support two-way communication, it can only parse result of own DLL request and do new call to DLL with new arguments. Thus, I need break Python control flow for temporary return partial results to DLL (and MT4) from Python and wait for new request from MT4.

How can I create this (ugly) presudo-two-way inteaction in Python style? I need some [continuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) functional, but yield work in function-scope only, when I need yield like exception: from bottom to top of call stack, and ability to return control flow to previous yield point by calling main.next() in the top Python script.

MT4 pseudo-code:

```
new_args = ...
while (true) {
  cmds = DLL_GetCommands(new_args);
  if (! cmd) { // No commands from Python
    break;
  }
  new_args = _parseCommand(cmds);
}
```

DLL pseudo-code:

```
char* __declspec(dllexport) DLL_GetCommands(char* args) {
    // Python already initialized.
    // Some python script already executed
    // and I have local scope of this execution.
    PyObject var = ...search some object variable in Python...
    // var is instance of Advert class
    return PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(var, "parse_tick", args, NULL);
}
```

Python code:

```
class Handler():
    def some_cpp_request(self, a, b):
        yield 'some_cpp_request'
        # After second call to Advert.parse_tick() control flow should return here.

class Advert():
    def __init__(self):
        self.h = Handler()

    # This method and all what it call should work as single generator
    def parse_tick(self):
        for i in range(2):
            self._some_method(i, i)

    def _some_method(self, a, b):
        self.h.some_cpp_request(a, b)
```

---

**[UPDATE]** After great advices from abarnert I have work solution:

```
class Handler():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cmds = []
        self.cmds_results = []

    def some_cpp_request(self, a, b):
        self.cmds.append(("SOME_CPP_REQUEST", a, b))
        yield
        # Here self.cmds_results contains MT4 response.

class Advert():
    def __init__(self):
        self.h = Handler()

    def parse_tick(self):
        for i in range(2):
            yield from self._some_method(i, i)

        return 'xxx'

    def _some_method(self, a, b):
        yield from self.h.some_cpp_request(a, b)

parser = Advert()
gen = parser.parse_tick()

# This loop should be written in DLL layer.
while True:
    next(gen)

    parser.h.cmds_results.clear()
    for cmd in parser.h.cmds:
        # Adding some results
        parser.h.cmds_results.append((cmd, 'SOME RESULT'))
    parser.h.cmds.clear()
```

**P.S.** More comfortable solution is create parallel thread (or process) instead of calling and catching yields: this not require replace all returns to yields. Two threads can communicate via two blocking queue.Queue's:

- Child thread:

  1. Put request to the request queue
  2. Blocking wait for new element in the response queue
- Main thread:

  1. Infinite blocking wait for new element in the request queue
  2. Put response to the request queue

If request is None, then break infinite loop for finish runtime: child and main threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `yield` in your Python code, just do it:

```
def parse_tick(self):
    for i in range(2):
        yield self._some_method(i, i)
```

Calling a Python generator function—whether you do so from Python or from C—gives you an iterator. Each time you get the `next` value from the iterator, it reactivates the generator function after the last `yield` point.

And [working with iterators from C](http://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/iter.html) is easy. Here's some pseudocode (like your existing pseudocode, skipping error handling, refcounting, etc.):

```
PyObject *iterator = PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(var, "parse_tick", args, NULL);
PyObject *item = NULL;
while (item = PyIter_Next(iterator)) {
    do_stuff_with(item);
}
```

---

What about exceptions? Not a problem. If you raise an exception from a generator function that you're iterating in Python, the `next` raises that exception to the caller. If you're iterating it in C, the `PyIter_Next` returns the same `NULL` that it does for the iterator being finished, so how do you tell them apart? By checking [`PyErr_Occurred()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/exceptions.html#PyErr_Occurred).

---

Alternatively, you can just pass a callback function into the Python code, and your Python code call that callback with each value instead of `yield`ing each one. This is what apps that embed Python have traditionally done. But if you're already thinking in generators, you don't need to fall back to the old way.

---

First, it sounds like you want to repurpose exceptions so that `raise`ing an exception automatically acts like a `yield` that can be resumed from. That doesn't work. A function that isn't a generator function can't be resumed, period. And even a function that *is* a generator function can only be resumed after a `yield`, not after a `raise` (or `return`). There's just no way around that; it would radically change the semantics of what `raise` (and `return`) do.

So, you are going to have to turn the lower-level functions that you want to drive like generators into actual generators. (Either that, or break them up into smaller functions and call them in sequence, or turn them into objects that maintain explicit state and resume on `__call__`, or something else that will be even more work than doing it the idiomatic way.)

---

Next, it sounds like like you want to have implicitly nested generators. Python generators don't work that way. If you call a generator function, you get back an iterator. Even if you yourself are also a generator function, it can't yield values on your behalf. If you want nesting, you have to make it explicit, like this:

```
def _some_method(self, a, b):
    yield a
    yield b

def parse_tick(self):
    for i in range(2):
        yield from self._some_method(i, i)
```

Notice that the caller (whether C or Python) doesn't have to know that `parse_tick` is actually delegating to other generators to do its work, or that `_some_method` is suspended somewhere. It just asks `parse_tick` for the next value, and all it sees is that it gets back `0`, then the next time `0` again, then `1`, then `1`, and then it's done.

And `parse_tick` doesn't have to remember that it has a suspended `_some_method` lying around either, because it's suspended in the middle of the `yield from`; the next time it resumes, it'll automatically resume the `_some_method` call—or, if that call is exhausted, continue on to the next line of code.

[PEP 380](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) attempts to explain the rationale behind this design, and how to use it, if I haven't made it clear. Greg Ewing also has [a great tutorial](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python/yield-from/yield_from.html) on using `yield from`. There's no way I could explain as much as his examples in an SO answer, even if I were half as good at explaining as he is.

---

Alternatively, you can use the `send` method on generators. If you look carefully, `yield` and `yield from` are expressions, with values, not statements. If you drive a generator by calling `next` on it, the value of the expression is just `None`, which isn't very useful. But by calling the `send` method on a generator, you can not only ask it to resume, but also give it a value to resume with. (You can also call `throw` to raise an exception into the generator, if you need to.) This lets you write your flow of control in terms of top-down coroutines—which I think isn't what you want here, but read [PEP 342](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/) and see.

---

You can also build on `yield from` to build bottom-up coroutines, which I think may be what you want. If you go back to Greg Ewing's page, the last example shows how to do this. And if you put the last two features together with a simple composable "future" abstraction… well, take a look at 3.4's new [`asyncio`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-task.html) module for an idea of what you can do.

Comment: I understood your suggestion, but I don't want to change Python code as you propose. I want write a lot of nested Python code without delivering yield from top to bottom. I want single yield in `Handle.some_cpp_request()` and float up to `Advert.parse_tick()` like an exception was thrown in `some_cpp_request()` and if try-except exists in `parse_tick()`. After some MT4-DLL interaction I want call `next(Advert.parse_tick())` or like `next(exception)` for return control flow to `Handle.some_cpp_request()` yield point. It is possible?

Comment: @SergeyNevmerzhitsky: `yield` in Python is inherently one level deep, not nested. Let me edit the answer to show some options.